# How to reference previously started processes in an Elixir supervisor

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I am starting a Supervisor that monitors two children. The second child needs a reference to the first. It seams like this should be possible because by using the `one_for_rest` strategy I can make sure that if the first dies the second is restarted.

```
children = [
  supervisor(SupervisorA, [arg1]),
  supervisor(SupervisorB, [arg2, ref_to_supervisor_a_process]),
]

supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_rest)
```

*Ideally without having to globally name either process.*

Answer (score 1):

`SupervisorA` can supply the `name:` option to `Supervisor.start_link/3`.

`SupervisorB` can then use `Process.whereis/1` to resolve the name to a `pid` or just send messages to the named process.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_link/3
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#whereis/1

Comment: Hi thanks, My aim is to do without having to use a global name for either process. The supervisor that runs both these supervisors might be started more than once

Comment: How about the registry? 
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html#content

Comment: I'm not sure registry offers any value, I would still have to come up with a random key in the registry to avoid clashes required to start the top level supervisor more than once

Comment: Looks like elixir 1.5 has a facility to hook into the child initialisation process: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html#init/2

Comment: I think that was always there, unless I'm mistaken this doesn't actually help

Comment: The `init` callback was always there, but the new function `Supervisor.init` allows you to dynamically construct values that will be passed to the children, such as a key that could be used with a registry for the children to discover each other.

Comment: Actually, I'm facing the same problem. I want to create a supervisor whenever a TCP connection establishes, and that supervisor supervises several children that need to be directly linked to each other so that they die together. The supervisor is in turn supervised by a `DynamicSupervisor`. I've tried to call `Supervisor.start_child` in the `init` callback, only got an error `process attempted to call itself`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Supervisor.Spec.supervisor/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html#supervisor/3) returns a [`spec`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/90296aa680dc9bf46517a9b69b54dc589a77b756/lib/elixir/lib/supervisor/spec.ex#L237).

One might pass it through:

```
{id, _, _, _, _, _} = sup_a = supervisor(SupervisorA, [arg1])
children = [
  sup_a,
  supervisor(SupervisorB, [arg2, id]),
]
```

Comment: There are many ways to retrieve the PID by `id`, e. g. [`Supervisor.which_children/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1). The latter works even if the original process died and the PID changed.

Comment: Would you not also need to pass in a reference to the supervisor pid